# How to fix "No such file or directory" when adding application with alternatives in Linux

Tags: linux, java

When running the command

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/java/latest/bin/jar 20000
```

in Linux I get the error

```
failed to read link /usr/bin/jar: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It turns out the fix is to run the following commands:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/jar
sudo rm /var/lib/alternatives/jar
sudo alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/java/latest/bin/jar 20000
```

you can confirm that the steps above worked with:

```
which jar
```

I'd say that those steps are pretty generic and could be used for other alternative applications too.

See http://johnglotzer.blogspot.com/2012/09/alternatives-install-gets-stuck-failed.html for more information.